# Prove that $\{ 1, e^x, e^{2x}, e^{3x}, e^{4x} \} \;$ is a linearly independent set in space of infinitely differentiable functions, $C ^\infty (R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\{ 1, e^x, e^{2x}, e^{3x}, e^{4x} \} \;$ is a linearly independent set in space of infinitely differentiable functions,  $C ^\infty (R)$

What I tried is next:

To prove that $\{ 1, e^x, e^{2x}, e^{3x}, e^{4x} \} \;$ is linearly independent then I have to prove that the only one solution to the next linear combination:

$\alpha_1*1+ \alpha_2 *e^x+ \alpha_3* e^2x+ \alpha_4* e^3x+ \alpha_5* e^4x = 0 \quad $ is: $\quad \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = \alpha_4 = \alpha_5 = 0 $

Step 1: I found the derivative of both sides of the equation and the result is:

$ \alpha_2 *e^x+ 2\alpha_3* e^{2x}+ 3\alpha_4* e^{3x}+ 4\alpha_5* e^{4x} = 0 $

Step 2: Then I divided both sides by $e^x$ and the result is:

$ \alpha_2 + 2\alpha_3* e^x+ 3\alpha_4* e^{2x}+ 4\alpha_5* e^{3x} = 0 $

Then I repeat some times more steps 1 and 2, and I got: $24\alpha_5 = 0   \to \alpha_5 = 0 $

So I can replace that result in the equation and do it again with $\alpha_4, \alpha_3, \alpha_2 \; $and$ \; \alpha_1$
and get that $ \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = \alpha_4 = \alpha_5 = 0 $

But I'm not sure if that's right.

Comment: Linearly independent over what field? Presumably the real numbers?

Comment: **HINT:** The equation 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{nx}=0$$
Is a *polynomial* with the substitution $u=e^x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Assume there exist $ (a,b,c,d,f)\in \Bbb R ) $ such that

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \;\; F(x)=$$
$$a+be^x+ce^{2x}+de^{3x}+fe^{4x}=0$$

then
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=a=0$$
and

$$F(x)=e^x(b+ce^x+de^{2x}+fe^{3x})$$
$$=e^xG(x)=0$$
So
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R)\;\; G(x)=0$$
thus

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}G(x)=b=0$$
and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^5$ be a set of 5 inependent vectors in ${\mathbb R}^5$. Each vector $v_i$ has 5 components $\{v_{ij}\}_{j=1}^5$. Assume that we found $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^5$ not all zero such that $\sum_{j=1}^5\alpha_je^{jx}=0$ for all $x$. We choose $x_{ij}=(\ln v_{ij})/j$. It then follows that we can write 5 equations of the form:
$$\sum_{j=1}^5\alpha_je^{jx_{ij}}=\sum_{j=1}^5\alpha_je^{\ln v_{ij}}=\sum_{j=1}^5\alpha_j  v_{ij} =0$$
which imply that the vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^5$ are linearly dependent - contrary to the assumption.